# Is it possible to insert or update multiple documents with a single command in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am coming from MySQL where you can have a huge INSERT and add (or ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE) a bunch of rows in a single query rather than having a loop with separate queries for each row. It does not seem like there is an option like that in MongoDB. Is that correct?

I realize that is not exactly compatible with MongoDB object-based approach. It just seems somewhat inefficient to send thousands of commands when one will do, especially if the DB is on a separate server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bulk inserts will be available in a future version, currently planned for v2.1, see:

- [Allow mutlidoc (bulk) insert](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2395)

Most of the [language drivers](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers) already implement their own bulk/batch insert too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the low-level interface supports things like this:

```
db.nonsense.update({a: 'a'}, {$set: {b: 'X'}}, false, true);
```

And that's like this SQL:

```
update nonsense
set b = 'X'
where a = 'a'
```

You'll want to last parameter ([*multi*](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-update%28%29)) to be `true` or you won't update all the matching entries.

This might be of use:

> http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/SQL+to+Mongo+Mapping+Chart

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In [java](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Tutorial#JavaTutorial-AddingMultipleDocuments), this is what it looks like.